# How to run html with json files in SharePoint?

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am making SharePoint spaces for various departments in insurance company. One of them wants to save and share their outputs via SharePoint. That outputs are maps with risk areas. Because maps includes many data layers, all the files are in one folder.

I have uploaded a folder with CSS, JSON, JS and HTML files to the library in SharePoint, but when I doubleclicked on HTML file, the page will not load. I think it's due to the JSON files.

What I need is to run whole page correctly with simple doubleclick.

Can anyone give me advice how to run other files supporting HTML with doubleclicking on HTML file?

Thank you.

Comment: We need more context to be able to answer your question. Can you show us what your HTML and JS files look like?

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot show HTML and JS files in public.

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to open/preview html file in your browser? If yes, then can you please let me know if other html files are opening in your browser ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue. To get the HTML to play in the browser (without SharePoint trying to make you download it), you need to rename the HTML file to an ASPX file.

To do this, you need to be in the Windows Explorer view (from a document library, go Library > Open with Explorer). Then change the file name from index.html to index.aspx.

However, if you're also using JSON files, that could be an issue. SharePoint prohibits you from uploading JSON files unfortunately.